# SVG - Draw shapes along the circle path

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

How to draw shapes as a stroke for `Circle` in SVG ?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something already? StackOverflow is not a place to request code, but a place to help others figure out their issues. We'd love to see a piece of code you tried.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="3" fill="transparent" />
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
    </svg>
```

Adjust the `stroke-width` and  `stroke-dasharray`